# Proving $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sin(e^{-x})}{x^{p-2}(x-1)^q}\right) = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I prove the following limit for every $p,q \in \mathbb R$?

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sin(e^{-x})}{x^{p-2}(x-1)^q}\right) = 0$$

For example, I tried using absolute value together with the squeeze theorem, while I believe it might work if $p-2+q > 0$ it would fail otherwise. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Well, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sin(e^{-x})}{e^{-x}} = 1$. That $e^{-x}$ decays much faster than any polynomial grows as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: While it's true, but I'm trying to write a formal proof..

Comment: $\mathrm{e}^x > \frac{x^n}{n!}$ for any $n\in \mathbb N$ and $x>0$.

Comment: How formal? $\epsilon-\delta$, or you are allowed to use standard limits? If standard limits are allowed then it's literally the product rule with terms $\frac{\sin(e^{-x})}{e^{-x}}$ and $e^{-x}x^{2-p}(x-1)^{-q}$. The former has a limit of $1$, the latter has the limit $0$ regardless of the values of $p$ and $q$.

Answer (score 4):

$[1]$.Take $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ such that $n-|p-2|-|q|>1.$

Now $x>0 \implies$ $ e^x=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(x^j/j!)>x^n/n!>0.$

So $x>0\implies$ $ |\sin (e^{-x})|<|e^{-x}|=e^{-x}<n!/x^n.$

And $x>2\implies x^n\cdot x^{p-2}\cdot (x-1)^q\ge$

$\ge x^n\cdot x^{-|p-2|}\cdot (x-1)^{-|q|}\ge$

$\ge x^n\cdot x^{-|p-2|}\cdot x^{-|q|}=$

$=x^{n-|p-2|-|q|}>x>0.$

Therefore $x>2\implies \left|\frac{\sin(e^{-x})}{x^{p-2}(x-1)^q}\right|<$ $\dfrac {n!}{x}.$

Note that $n$ is a fixed value chosen at line $[1]$ and is not related to any $x$.

Comment: If  you did not know the power series for $e^x$, you could use the Binomial Theorem. We need a bigger $n$ than in my answer. Let $[x]$ denote the largest integer not exceeding $x$ Now $x>1\implies e^x>(1+1)^{[x]}=\sum_{j=0}^{[x]}\binom {[x]}{j}>\binom {[x]}{n},$ if $[x]>n$. With a little more work and the fact that  $[x]>x-1$ we can now show $|2^{[x]}x^{p-2}(x-1)^q|\to\infty.$

Answer (score 0):

We have that $\sin t\le t$ for $t \to 0^+$  then assuming wlog $x>2$

$$\frac{\sin(e^{-x})}{x^{p-2}(x-1)^q} \le \frac{e^{-x}}{x^{p-2}(x-1)^q}\le \frac1{e^{x-1}(x-1)^{p-2+q}} \to 0$$

indeed it is trivially true for $p-2+q\ge 0$ and for $-a=p-2+q< 0$ since eventually $e^{x-1}\ge (x-1)^{a+1}$ we have

$$\frac1{e^{x-1}(x-1)^{p-2+q}} =\frac{(x-1)^a}{e^{x-1}}\le \frac1{x-1} \to 0$$